# Auditing trigger - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, triggers, audit

I am attempting to create a database trigger capable of creating a snapshot of a 'Transactions' table and storing it in an 'Audit' table along with information pertaining to the date of the inserting, updating or deleting of any rows of data.

Apologies in advance, but I'm very much a novice at this kinda stuff!

As it stands, my trigger is as follows:

```
create trigger AuditTransactions
on dbo.Transactions
after insert, update, delete
as

    if exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        if exists(select * from deleted)
        begin
            -- this is for an update
            update Audit
            set DeleteDate = getdate()
            where TransactionId in (select TransactionId from deleted)
        end 

        -- this is just for an insert
        insert into Audit
        select *, getdate() as CreateDate
        from inserted
    end
    else
    begin
        -- this is just for a delete
        update Audit
        set DeleteDate = getdate()
        where TransactionId in (select TransactionId from deleted)
    end

go
```

And my audit table appears as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
    [TransactionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [InvoiceType] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [InvoiceIssueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [InvoiceTotalexclVat] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [InvoiceTotalVat] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [InvoiceDiscount] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [InvoiceTotalPayable] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [AccountCode] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Reference1] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Reference2] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Reference3] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Level1CustomOrg] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Level2CustomOrg] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Level3CustomOrg] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Level4CustomOrg] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ScanLocation] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ScanDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [CaptureInkjetId] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CaptureBatchId] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CaptureDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [InputSource] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CurrencyCode] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [DebitCredit] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [OrderNumberHeader] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [SupplierName] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [BancPaySupplierId] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [SupplierIDERP] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DeliveryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CustomRef1] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef2] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef3] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef4] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef5] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef6] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef7] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef8] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef9] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef10] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef11] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef12] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef13] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef14] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomRef15] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CustomAmount1] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CustomAmount2] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CustomAmount3] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CustomAmount4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CustomAmount5] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CustomDate1] [datetime] NULL,
    [CustomDate2] [datetime] NULL,
    [Country1] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country2] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country3] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country4] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country5] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country6] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country7] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country8] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country9] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Country10] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CheckedOut] [bit] NULL,
    [CheckedOutDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [BlobUrl] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [GLCode] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [RejectReason] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [RejectComment] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ReferMessage] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [PaymentTerms] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [CheckedOutByUserId] [int] NULL,
    [LastUpdatedByUserId] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionFormatTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [RequestOriginalStatusTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [GLCodeComment] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [SenderOrganizationId] [int] NULL,
    [ReceiverOrganizationId] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionStatusTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [TransactionTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [OrganizationId] [int] NULL,
    [OrganizationId1] [int] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeleteDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

When attempting to execute the query for the trigger I am getting the following error message:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AuditTransactions, Line 17
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

This appears to be the 'insert into Audit' command, but I have no idea what to do from here!

Any help will be hugely appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: If `Transactions` table does not have `Create` and `Delete` dates, you need to add null for `DeleteDate` in insert. If it has, replace * with column list because - as it is now - you are trying to insert one column more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) seems to be rather poorly documented. For the `VALUES()` element, it states the following:

> If the values in the Value list are not in the same order as the columns in the table or **do not have a value for each column in the table**, `column_list` must be used to explicitly specify the column that stores each incoming value.

(**Emphasis** added)

However, it is my understanding and belief that the same constraint applies, no matter what the source of values/rows are - that unless you exactly match all columns in the table, you need to provide the `column_list`.

Now, for your instance, it may be easier if you just provide a value for *every* column in the table:

```
insert into Audit
select *, getdate() as CreateDate,null as DeleteDate
from inserted
```

Now, my other observation is that all this mucking about with conditional control flow is rather pointless - an `insert` of 0 rows will have no effect, and an `update` using `in` against an empty table will similarly have no effect. So I'd just have:

```
create trigger AuditTransactions
on dbo.Transactions
after insert, update, delete
as

    update Audit
    set DeleteDate = getdate()
    where TransactionId in (select TransactionId from deleted)

    insert into Audit
    select *, getdate() as CreateDate,null as DeleteDate
    from inserted
```

Comment: Absolutely superb, many thanks for the quick response and fantastic help. The query is now executing correctly and the trigger has been initialised and is performing exactly as anticipated. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into Audit
        select *, getdate() as CreateDate, null
        from inserted
```

Your "audit" table has more columns than you're inserting (the deleted date); you need to either name all the columns, or insert a null.

Stylistically, naming the columns is better - it makes it clear what goes where, and avoid bugs when you add new columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this convention so it's great to find that out!